# How do I install Ubuntu 23.04 on an encrypted Btrfs filesystem?

Tags: encryption, luks, btrfs, cryptsetup, 23.04

I currently use an encrypted Btrfs filesystem (cryptsetup+luks), which I could set up easily using the Ubuntu 22.10 setup.  With Ubuntu 23.04, I only managed to install it on an encrypted LVM+ext4 partition.  Is there still a way to use an encrypted Btrfs FS?

Comment: It seems the new installer lacks a number of advanced features - such as ZFS installation and also BTRFS encryption it would seem.. 